# I'm in the U.S.  What are vehicles to invest in international stocks?

Tags: united-states, investing, international-trading, pink-sheets

I'm interested in investing in companies that are trading in Thailand, Malaysia, Norway.  I am in U.S. and have a Scottrade account.  I know that some of the companies don't trade on U.S. stock exchanges and don't have ADRs.  There is an option to buy via Pink Sheets.  I was wondering if there are other avenues that are out there?

Comment: You should realize that with ADR you have some sanity on your investments. Would you be willing to rely on an alien government in an alien land to take care of your money ?

Comment: Good point about ADRs being more secure. However, I'm still curious about different ways to invest. Just to broaden my horizons. Thanks.

Comment: THD is iShare Thailand ETF.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into specific market targeted mutual funds or ETF's. For Norway, for example, look at NORW.

If you want to purchase specific stocks, then you'd better be ready to trade on local stock exchanges in local currency. ETrade allows trading on some of the international stock exchanges (in Asia they have Hong Kong and Japan, in Europe they have the UK, Germany and France, and in the Americas they have the US and Canada). Some of the companies you're interested in might be trading there.

Answer (score 1):

Interactive Brokers offers many foreign markets (19 countries) for US based investors. You can trade all these local markets within one universal account which is very convenient in my view.

[IB offering](http://individuals.interactivebrokers.com/en/general/whyib/PDF-GlobalOfferings.php)